# distance between peaks of the graph

Tags: matlab, max, curve-fitting, gaussian, normal-distribution

I have a curve with multiple peaks and I want to find the distance between the peaks. I want to know which peaks I should include. That is I want to fit multiple Gaussian distributions to this curve and then take the peak of each Gaussian distribution. I also want to use something like AIC/BIC or regularization so that it won't overfit. My code is in MATLAB. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Figure of the sample curve
[image: Figure for the sample curve]

Comment: You should indicate which language/library you want to use and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My codes are in matlab

Comment: Like this? https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/peak-analysis.html#d119e1309